# How to download a file which have download button in the webpage (https url) using java

Tags: java, curl

We have url(Ex:https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/planes-numeracion/descarga-publica.xhtml) that contain file download button.

[image]

As per requirement need download that file using java from that URL. But it has the download button(manual) so am unable to implement java code

I tried following

```
try{
    url = "curl -k -o data.csv https://sns.ift.org.mx:8081/sns-frontend/planes-numeracion/descarga-publica.xhtml";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "/bin/sh" , "-c" , url});
    exitStatus = p.waitFor();
} catch(Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception "+e);
}
```

Comment: **Never**  catch exceptions without handle it `} catch(Exception e) {}`. Atleast log them

Comment: Your code downloads the html page. It should call a function that is behind the download- buttom

Comment: @Jens i am facing the same issue but what if URL won't render automatic downloading ?

Comment: If you can download with curl what makes you think you *can't* download it with Java?

Comment: am unable to download with curl also i mentioned that i tried that one @g00se

Comment: Sorry - missed that. You're probably going to have to use a Java API that supports JavaScript